# How to create banded column in GridPanel?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to create Banded Column in Ext JS `GridPanel` ??

Comment: Found in group-header-grid.js!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

An Example from

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columnLines: true,
        columns: [{
            text     : 'Company',
            flex     : 1,
            sortable : false,
            dataIndex: 'company'
        }, {
            text: 'Stock Price',
            columns: [{
                text     : 'Price',
                width    : 75,
                sortable : true,
                renderer : 'usMoney',
                dataIndex: 'price'
            }, {
                text     : 'Change',
                width    : 75,
                sortable : true,
                renderer : change,
                dataIndex: 'change'
            }, {
                text     : '% Change',
                width    : 75,
                sortable : true,
                renderer : pctChange,
                dataIndex: 'pctChange'
            }]
        }, {
            text     : 'Last Updated',
            width    : 85,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        }],
        height: 350,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Grouped Header Grid',
        renderTo: 'grid-example',
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        }
    });
```